# Does bash recognize a variable declaration as string if you do not put the quotation marks?

Tags: bash

```
name=Jackson
echo $name
```

This will display Jackson.

```
name="Jackson"
echo $name
```

This will also display Jackson.

So I assume by putting quotation marks around a variable it is making it a string. What would name=Jackson technically be? Would it also be recognized as a string?

Comment: there is a difference: try `name=Michael Jackson ; echo "$name"` and `name="Michael Jackson" ; echo "$name"` . Very different. In usual, always put surrounding quotes when you define and use variables. `cd "${var}"` is much better than `cd $var` which would silently go to the homedir instead of protesting if var is not defined... Unless you need to explicitely call each separate elements, ie in a `for i in $var ; do something ; done`

Comment: when you say `name=Michael Jackson ;` you are setting a variable "name" to a value "Michael" and calling a program/cmd "Jackson". Bash will retune an error with a message "command not found" as bash is looking for a program called "Jackson". so, in the end, the variable "name" is not set.

Answer (score 6):

Linux environment variables are always strings. The quotes are only needed if you have special characters (shell metacharacters or whitespace) in your string. Shell metacharacters are:

```
<>()[]{}*?$|&#\;`'"
```

With $, \ and ` the double quotes are not sufficient as they are even expanded within them. There you need either single quotes or escape them with \.

As was noted in a comment, bash has special typed variables, but they are rarely needed and by default all bash variables are strings too.

Comment: +1 because the core of the answer is correct. However, more advanced shells do have other data types besides just strings. Bash lets you say things like `typeset -i foo=2` to get an integer variable `$foo` with the value `2`.

Comment: @WarrenYoung In what sense is that any different from `foo=2`?

Comment: Nb. There is no such thing as an "integer variable" in bash: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html They're still strings; `typeset -i foo=2` is exactly the same as `foo=2` and `foo="2"`.

Comment: @goldilocks It is not exactly the same. Run `foo=0x${foo}; echo $foo"` or `foo=bar;echo $foo`to see a difference in behavior. There are definitely integer typed variables in bash.

Comment: @jlliagre : Cheers.  Still, it shouldn't be considered a true *type* -- `declare -i x=123456789` will still be a 9 byte string, flagged with a particular property.  I realize that's a mostly a pointless distinction in practice, but it doesn't hurt to be aware of it either.

Comment: @goldilocks `declare -i x=123456789012345678901234567890;echo ${#x}` would display `30` if that was true, but that's not the case.

Comment: @goldilocks: Another test to show the distinction: `typeset -i foo=2 ; foo=foo+4 ; echo $foo` vs `bar=2 ; bar=bar+4 ; echo $bar`. (Whitespace is significant in the arithmetic. You can't add spaces between the variable and operators unless you quote them, due to Bash command parsing rules.)

Comment: @jlliagre : No, because again it's being interpreted first (and, at least here, obviously via a 32-bit int -- it will also wrap around).  Of course at this point if it looks like a duck and walks like a duck it might as well be a duck ;)  All apologies for picking a silly argument, I concede the point!

Comment: Your missing the point, declare -i sets what the next assignment will be interpreted as, it is not meant to be a type converter. If you try to assign a string value again after using it, you will get zero. That is why the keyword 'typeset' is obsolete [from bash docs], because people are getting the wrong impression i suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Bash is not strongly typed;<sup>1</sup> the only significant difference is between scalar and compound types (arrays).  *Scalars are always considered strings*, but there are "numerical strings" which can be used arithmetically:

```
a="5"
b=10

echo "$a + $b = "$(($a+$b));
```

A "numerical string" is simply a string which contains only digits and so can be converted to an integer value.  All scalar values in bash are still just strings, and **the quotes in the declaration here are irrelevant.** `a=5` is EXCATLY the same as `a="5"`. If you compare `$a` and `$b` using (e.g.) `-lt` they are treated as numbers.  If you compare them using `<` they are treated lexicographically.  It is the operator/context that makes the determination, not a characteristic of the variable.

You can also declare a variable with an "integer flag", and this will cause the declared value to  be interpreted as an arithmetic expression:

```
x=10/2
echo "$x" # output: 10/2
declare -i x=10/2
echo "$x" # output: 5
declare -i x=what
echo "$x" # output: 0
```

Subsequently, anything assigned to that variable will be interpreted arithmetically:

```
a=5
declare -i b=10
a=$a/5
b=$b/5
echo "$a $b" #output: 5/5 2
a=hello
b=world
echo $a$b #output hello0
```

But the content of the variable is still a (numerical) string.  The integer flag restricts the content of the string and affects the interpretation of values assigned to it.

<sup>1</sup> It's not simple dynamic typing either, as the case of the declared integer demonstrates.  Maybe we could call it a sort of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), or, as per the [*Bash Advanced Scripting Guide*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html), it is "untyped".

Comment: Declaring a variable as integer definitely has subsequent consequences as from then, the variable cannot be used to store (random) strings.

Comment: @jlliagre Ya got me.  Edited.

Comment: @goldilocks "Bash is not strongly typed;1 the only significant difference is between scalar and compound types (arrays). Scalars are always considered strings". May I ask, what is your source of this information? I couldn't find it in any Bash documentation.

Comment: @yroc There's this from the "Advanced Scripting Guide": http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html (worked that into the footnote above). Beyond that I'd say I was just stating the obvious: The fact that it does not have explicit types sort of by definition means it is not strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference: 
try

```
unset name
name="Michael Jackson" ; echo "$name"
```

and

```
unset name #to reset name, see comments
name=Michael Jackson ; echo "$name"
```

It's very different: on the 2nd, it tries to start the "Jackson" command, passing it the "name=Michael" environment. So it will complain that "Jackson: command not found"
I have to add the `unset name` to "reset" name, as the next line's `name=Michael` part will be only passed to the "Jackson" command (and only to that command), and is therefore NOT done on the calling shell level! (which therefore would still have the `name="Michael Jackson"` from the 1st command, if we didn't set it back to `""` before our 2nd try. So the "echo $name" would confusingly still display "Michael Jackson" if we didn't forget that 1st try.)

In usual, **always** put surrounding double-quotes when you define, and especially when you use variables.

```
cd "${var}"
```

is much better than

```
cd $var
```

The 2nd version would silently go to the homedir instead of protesting if $var is not defined...

Then only take out the surrounding double-quotes only when you **know** that you **need** to separate each elements of the variable, ie in a :

```
for i in $var ; do something_using_i ; done
```